# Fire UILocalNotification every day, but everyday at a specific time

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to fire `UILocalNotification`'s for 8 days long, but everyday I want to fire them on a different specific time. So e.g.:
 
Day 1: fire notification at 11:00 and 12:00
Day 2: fire notification at 12:00 and 14:00
Day 3: fire notification at 13:00 and 16:00 
Day 4: fire notification at 14:00 and 18:00
Day 5: fire notification at 16:00 
Day 6: fire notification at 18:00
Day 7: fire notification at 18:00
Day 8: fire notification at 18:00
(The times are just examples)

I've already been doing things with `repeatInterval`, but that's probably not the thing;

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:now];
[components setHour:22];
[components setMinute:15];

UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notification1.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
notification1.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[notification1 setAlertBody:@"Test notification"];



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];
```

Comment: What do you except from us? Code? Why should we give you code for free? We'll help you if you have problem, but not this way. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The `-repeatInterval` property can be used to repeat a notification at specific unit(day,week...) at the same time. Furthermore you can't set more than 64 notif per app.
 what you can do is set your notifications with different times with a 
`repeatInterval` on a week unit.